# Working out tallest formation possible

Tags: geometry

In a stack of logs, each row has one less log than the row below.
With 2015 logs, what is the tallest possible stack?

I thought I'd start by doubling a 9-log stack and putting one upside up,one upside down, to make a parallelogram, but then I got stuck. How do I proceed?

Comment: How can you have 9 logs on top of 9 logs if `each row has one less log than the row below`?

Comment: By turning two stacks into a trapezium,as I mentioned in my question.

Comment: Also, a 9-log stack means 4 logs at  the bottom,3 in the middle and 2 at the top

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your trapezoid approach correctly, you are doubling a $9$-log stack so that you can algebraically calculate the number of logs as

$$
\frac{3 \textrm{ logs high } \times (4 \textrm{ logs at the bottom } + 2 \textrm{ logs at the top })}{2} = 9 \textrm{ logs } \\
$$

This is a similar approach used by the Pythagoreans to calculate triangular numbers because these can be arranged as an equilateral triangle just like your stack of logs. The only difference is that you seem to be chopping the triangle at the top, to $2$ logs in your $9$-log example.

Instead, it might be simpler to suspend our imagination for a moment and assume the logs are real numbers to calculate the $n$th partial sum for $2015$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{n \times (n + 1)}{2} &=& 2015 \\
n^2 + n - 4030 &=& 0\\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

This is a quadratic equation so you can then use the quadratic formula to find $n$

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
n &=& \frac{-1 \pm \sqrt{1 - 4 \times (-4030)}}{2} \\
n &\approx& -63.98 \quad \textrm{ or } \quad n \approx 62.98 \\
\end{eqnarray}
$$

To resume our imagination, the number of rows cannot be negative and they cannot be fractional either so the tallest possible stack is $62$ logs high.

Comment: Thanks but can you please simply explain how to use the quadratic formula

Comment: I could but [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_formula) or [Purplemath](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/quadform.htm) would explain much better than me.

Comment: I read Purplemath's lesson about  the quadratic formula, but I didn't understand the part about deviring. Can you please explain what you do, how you do it and why.

Comment: The comments section of this question might not be the most conducive place for so much explanations. I would suggest you ask another question specifically about using the quadratic formula and be sure to detail the steps that you've tried; what you will get out of the answers often depends on the effort you put in the question.

Comment: @ezekiel:  He is looking for the largest [triangular number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_number) below $2015$, which I believe meets the requirement.  Your stack ends up with the same number of logs in each layer (it looks like $6$ to me if you put the stacks side by side) so it violates the one less in each successive layer requirement.

Comment: Thanks everyone. I will keep this in mind.